# Couldn't understand the ternary operator behavior

Tags: c, ternary

Output of the following program is : `3 1 3`

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = 3;
    *((a) ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c; // Couldn't understand expression
    printf("%d %d %d \n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

How ternary operator is working here for this output?

Comment: Which part is unclear? `a` is `0` so it should be obvious which option is chosen in both cases.

Comment: Tell us what you think the output should be along with your reasoning and we will tell you if you are right or wrong.

Comment: I think the question is about the references being used in the first ternary operator. It is a bit confusing.

Comment: Replace the ternary operator by an `if ... else` ?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard especially confusing since they're not references; they're variable addresses, of which one (being returned from the ternary condition) is being *dereferenced*. Methinks you're on to something, however. Perhaps the OP just doesn't do pointers.

Comment: @WhozCraig Stupid question here: what is the difference between a reference and a variable address? (I haven't used C in a while; I mostly do Java, which doesn't really do pointers, except when it kind of does.)

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Addresses are the fundamental "values" of pointers, where-as references, (the C++ term) a different, more restrictive (and thats a good thing) beast. See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 *( (a) ? &b : &a) =     a ? b : c ;
     ^                   ^
     = 0                 = 0
     ==false             ==false
```

so the above expression:

```
 *( &a) =  c ;
```

that is:

```
     a =  c ;
```

because `c = 3;`, so it give:

```
     a =  3 ;
```

`b` is `1` and `c` is `3` in your declaration(remains unchanged).

Comment: read: [how Conditional operator works?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28programming%29#If_expressions)

Comment: So if a=1, then result would be 1,1,3?

Comment: @Jim suppose  if `a = 1`  then expression would be == to `b = b`, and yes then o/p will be 1, 1, 3

Answer (score 0):

My C is a little weak, so if I'm off-base here, someone let me know.

Assuming you're talking about the expression `*((a) ? &b : &a)` (and that you know how the ternary operator works generally), here's how it breaks down:

The condition `(a)` is evaluated: when using an `int` in a boolean, `0` evaluates to false, while positive (or non-zero?) values evaluate to true — in this case, `a == 0` is false.

The ternary then returns the value `&b` if true and `&a` if false (in this case it's false, so it returns `&a`).

The value thus returned is a reference to a variable; the asterisk before the surrounding parentheses dereferences this reference, so the expression `*((a) ? &b : &a)` evaluates to the variable — but not the value of — `a` (if `a` where not `0`, the expression would evaluate to `b`).

That line then assigns to this variable (in this case `a`) the value of the second ternary expression, which I assume you can figure out.

The final effect is that it assigns the value of `c` to the variable `a`, which explains the output.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the [ternary conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) has higher [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) than the assignment operator. The ternary conditional has the form:

> *`condition`* **`?`** *`true-result`* **`:`** *`false-result`*

If `condition` is true, the result is `true-result`, otherwise the result is `false-result`. The operator is short-circuiting in the sense that only one of the results is ever evaluated.

This operator can be used for conditional assignment. For example:

```
int days_of_year = is_leap_year ? 366 : 365;
```

The result of the ternary conditional is an r-value. This means that the result is a value that cannot be the target of an assignment. However, there is a trick that can be used to use the ternary conditional with pointers and [dereference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) so as to get the behavior of conditionally assigning to one variable or another.

```
int x;
int y;
*(need_x ? &x : &y) = 0;
```

While the result of a ternary condition is an r-value, the result of a dereference is an l-value. This means the result of the dereference can be used as the target of an assignment.

Your code uses both of these ideas in combination.